OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier zoom-in and center in leaflet
Is there a way to have the same zoom-in and center behaviour with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfy as with MarkerCluster?
I have a geoJson file with samples=features which are filtered based on a property into 3 layers (in this test example). Most of the locations have multiple samples. Leaflet with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfy principally does what I want. For locations with only one sample the popup opens on a zoomed-in map which is what is wanted. For locations with multiple samples, a first click on a marker opens the spider but does not zoom in on the selected marker. A second click on a spiderfied marker zooms in and opens the popup but at the "wrong" place.
How can I get the zoom-in and center on the map if I click on a marker in oms? Seems simple but I didn't get it to work. I also unsuccessfully tested versions with oms.addlistener{'spiderfy' ...}.
Here is a jsfiddle link(OverlappingMarkerSpiderfy geoJson). If you click twice on the red marker you can see the problem.
Key code is:
//define oms
const oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {
  keepSpiderfied: true,
});

//assign layers and map data
for (var i = 0; i < myAgeWindows.length; i++) {
  var features = L.geoJson(MygeoJson, {
    //filter samples to layers defined in myAgeWindowBorder[]
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
          // filtering geoJson for data into layers i
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: L.divIcon({
         className: 'material-icons',
         html: "<span = class='material-icons " + myColors[i] + "'>place</span>",
         iconSize: [24, 24],
         iconAnchor: [12, 24], 
        })
      })
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, latlng) {
      oms.addMarker(latlng);
    },

  }).addTo(map);
  layerControl.addOverlay(features, myAgeWindows[i]);
} //end for

//define popup and add to eventlistener
var popup = new L.Popup({
  offset: L.point(0, -15)
});

oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
  var myPopupInfo = ("<b>Poseidon-ID: </b>" + marker.feature.properties.Poseidon_ID);
  popup.setContent(myPopupInfo);
  popup.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
  popup.setContent(myPopupInfo);
  map.openPopup(popup);

  // center map and zoom on the clicked marker
  map.setView(marker.getLatLng(), 5);          //THIS LINE OF CODE IS NOT GIVING THE DESIRED OUTCOME
}); `

